# Selenium TestNG Throw Exception get null pointer exception while Opening Chilld browser

Tags: java, selenium, maven, frameworks, testng

In above code at this line:

```
Set<String> statmentwindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

the compiler will throw an exception and the Test Case will be failed. Exception was like:

```
Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.getWindowHandles()" because "Pages.FundsPage.driver" is null
```

Code trials:

```
public void fundClick() throws InterruptedException
    {
            btnfunds.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            btnaddfunds.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Set<String> statmentwindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
            System.out.println(statmentwindow);
            String[] win2 =new String[10];
            Iterator<String> itr = statmentwindow.iterator();
            for (int i=0;i<statmentwindow.size();i++) 
            {
                win2[i]=itr.next();
                System.out.println(win2[i]);
            }
            driver.switchTo().window(win2[1]);
            driver.close():
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you using the *`Pages.FundsPage.driver`* instance within the first two lines which are successfully executed within `fundClick()` method.

You were using *`btnfunds`* element. Hence when you try to access ***driver*** instance, you see the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.getWindowHandles()" because "Pages.FundsPage.driver" is null
```

Comment: so where i need to declare pages.Funds.driver instance